# Reverse RowNumberer in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

in ExtJS 3.3.1 how can I get the rowNumberer header in desc order, currently displays 1,2,3,4,...

this is the header example

```
..
{header:'id', dataIndex:'id', hidden:true },
new Ext.grid.RowNumberer(),
{header:'Folio:', dataIndex:'folio' },
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could just override the renderer function.  Or if you're going to re-use this technique, derive your own ReverseRowNumberer class with its own renderer.  Here's the existing renderer (in 4.1):

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store) {
    if (this.rowspan){
        metaData.cellAttr = 'rowspan="'+this.rowspan+'"';
    }

    metaData.tdCls = Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-cell-special';
    return store.indexOfTotal(record) + 1;
}
```

You could keep the same metadata styling and change the final return value to

```
return store.getCount() - store.indexOfTotal(record);
```

I don't have a running 3.x Ext install, but it seems like the renderer signature remains the same between 3.x and 4.x. If you look at the docs for the store, you would see that you have `indexOf` available in 3.x.  Or you could just use the `row` index value directly.  These would be easy and valid if you didn't have paging enabled.  If you did have paging, you could use the store's `getTotalCount` method and somehow find your index yourself.  The point is that for most uses of a Store, you have enough info available to you in the renderer method args to calculate the row number value you need.

```
renderer: function (value, meta, record, row, col, store) {
    // set up the meta styles appropriately, etc.

    // then:
    return store.getCount() - row;
}
```

Comment: indexOfTotal is not supported in the version I provided so it doesn't work.